# How many sites can Jekyll supports?

Tags: nginx, jekyll

I just made three sites by Jekyll and used different port to start them. I just use Nginx to configure them, but I found only two of them can run at the same time. Is there any configuration that I can set to configure the maximum number of sites that Jekyll can serve?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using Nginx for ? Jekyll can serve itself with a `jekyll serve` or `bundle exec jekyll serve`.

You can simply start three jekyll instances from three different command line prompt.

1. `bundle exec jekyll serve` that you can reach at http://127.0.0.1:4000
2. `bundle exec jekyll serve --port 8080` that you can reach at http://127.0.0.1:8080
3. `bundle exec jekyll serve --port 8081` that you can reach at http://127.0.0.1:8081